# How can I say "How can I be of any help?"

Tags: politesse, formulation-idiomatique

I know how to say "How can I help?" but I want to get the level a little bit higher by saying "How can I be of any help?"

What's the best way of saying this in French?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Or also:

> Comment puis-je vous être utile?

Comment: Hum... "En quoi puis-je vous être utile ?" seems more natural and idiomatic. You'll hear it from shopkeepers etc.

Answer (score 2):

"Puis-je [vous] être  d'un quelconque secours?"

It's the best fit for 'can I be of any help' and it's usually the most polite and correct way to say that In French.You'll find that expression often in books etc...

Comment: C'est un style très soutenu, très littéraire, très urbain.

Comment: Oui, ca fait un peu vieille France ... mais ca reste 'classe' et correct en tous les cas.

Comment: Exactement : la même impression d'excellence dans les rapports humains, exprimée cette fois dans une langue plus usuelle.

Comment: How about the more casual "puis-je vous être utile en quoi que ce soit?" kind of sentence? Not classy as you answer, still quite polite.

Answer (score 1):

You can say « Puis-je vous aider de quelque manière que ce soit ? »

Comment: This is very wordy. It's not wrong, but it's not really idiomatic unless there's some prior conversation.

Answer (score 1):

It could be « Puis-je vous aider ? »